# Creating Custom Android Notifications using Gluon-Mobile

Tags: java, android, javafx, gluon, gluon-mobile

I have created Android Notification using Gluon-Mobile using [localNotification](http://docs.gluonhq.com/charm/javadoc/4.3.2/com/gluonhq/charm/down/plugins/LocalNotificationsService.html).

But,this time I want to create custom Android Native Notification.
  I have been referring this [Go Native](http://docs.gluonhq.com/samples/gonative/) docs.
So,far I have Tried this Below .I have placed this code under **android/java/com/sample** package,

 but it's not working.

```
package com.sample;
import android.app.Activity;

import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.content.Context;
import javafxports.android.FXActivity;
import android.app.Notification;
/**
 *
 * @author Guru
  */
  public class NotificationsController extends Activity implements NotificationInteface
{
NotificationManager man;
Notification notification;
public    NotificationsController ()
{ man=(NotificationManager)FXActivity.getInstance().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
 notification= new Notification.Builder(this)
                            .setContentTitle("New mail from " + "test@gmail.com")
                            .setContentText("Subject").build();


 }

 public void showUp()
       {
 man.notify(0, notification);
       }
 }
```

And I have added this Activity in my AndroidManifest.xml Below.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.sample" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
    <supports-screens android:xlargeScreens="true"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.UPDATE_DEVICE_STATS"></uses-permission>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" android:targetSdkVersion="21"/>
    <application android:label="Sample" android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
     <activity android:name="javafxports.android.FXActivity" android:label="Sample" android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">
     <meta-data android:name="main.class" android:value="com.sample.Main"/>
     <meta-data android:name="debug.port" android:value="0"/>
     <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
     </intent-filter>
     </activity>
     <activity android:name="com.gluonhq.impl.charm.down.plugins.android.NotificationActivity"
        android:parentActivityName="javafxports.android.FXActivity">
     <meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY" 
               android:value="javafxports.android.FXActivity"/>
      </activity>
      <activity
        android:name="com.sample.NotificationsController" >
    </activity>
```

I have added this **NotificationsController** class to AndroidManifest.xml.So,that it cant be considered as the Activity.I don't know what I have missed.

Comment: It seems you want to "override" the Charm Down `NotificationActivity` from the LocalNotifications service? This is not possible unless you modify the LocalNotifications plugin itself, build and install the Charm Down library and use the local version. Or am I missing something?

Comment: it seems like you're correct ! @JoséPereda can you provide me any example !

Comment: Example? Just fork the Charm Down repository, and modify the `AndroidLocalNotificationsService` [class](https://bitbucket.org/gluon-oss/charm-down/src/5d8f643f7b3ed394421edd19add1daf1c51b5bc2/plugins/plugin-local-notifications/android/src/main/java/com/gluonhq/charm/down/plugins/android/AndroidLocalNotificationsService.java?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default). You can see that it is already using the android `Notification` API. Then build and install locally the library, and then use it instead of the official one.

Comment: I'll work it out ! @JoséPereda